# ¿Cómo hacer que funcione este servidor Socket en PHP?

Tags: php, socket, tcp

Estoy creando un servidor con sockets de PHP, he creado el archivo servidor.php y lo he subido a mi VPS. He creado un cliente.php para probar y lo abro desde localhost, el caso es que siempre me dice que es imposible conectar con el servidor mediante el puerto 10000.

Estos son los códigos (son muy simples para probar).

**servidor.php**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($socket,'127.0.0.1',10000);
socket_listen($socket);

echo "Esperando conexión\n\n";
$conn = false;
switch(@socket_select($r = array($socket), $w = array($socket), $e = array($socket), 60)) {
case 2:
echo "Conexión rechazada!\n\n";
break;
case 1:
echo "Conexión aceptada!\n\n";
$conn = @socket_accept($socket);
break;
case 0:
echo "Tiempo de espera excedido!\n\n";
break;
}
if ($conn !== false) {
  socket_write($conn, "TE HAS CONECTADO PERFECTAMENTE", srtlen("TE HAS CONECTADO PERFECTAMENTE"));
}
?>
```

**cliente.php**

```
<?php
$host = "IP DE MI VPS";

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$puerto = 10000;

if (socket_connect($socket, $host, $puerto))
{
echo "\nConexion Exitosa, puerto: " . $puerto;
$out = socket_read($socket, 2048);
echo $out;
}
else
{
echo "\nLa conexion TCP no se pudo realizar, puerto: ".$puerto;
}
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Para dejar el servidor abierto como daemon en linux utilizo el comando:

```
nohup php servidor.php > errores.log &
```

No sé porque no efectúa la conexión, supongo que abrá que abrir el puerto o algo. Es la primera vez que intento hacer algo así.

Comment: Intenta abriendo el puerto en el servidor.

Comment: @Jesús pudiste solucionar tu inconveniente? Tengo un servidor desde el cual requiero escuchar datos que me envia una controladora en la misma red donde tengo el servidor, pero no he podido recibir datos a mi servidor.

Answer (score 3):

Uno de los varios problemas es que al hacer

```
socket_bind($socket,'127.0.0.1',10000);
```

el socket solo escucha conexiones en la ip 127.0.0.1 (es decir, locales). Si quieres que escuche en la IP pública, debes usar esa IP. O bien usa '`0.0.0.0'`, que implicar escuchar en todas las direcciones disponibles.

Por otro lado, si el server es público muy probablemente tenga un firewall que filtra las conexiones entrantes (lo contrario sería muy preocupante), por lo cual deberías asegurarte de que ese port permita las conexiones entrantes.

Otra cosa: el `@` como prefijo en las llamadas a funciones de PHP hace que los warnigs y mensages de error no se vean. En general, es mala práctica. Y más todavía cuando estás tratando de debuggear o entender por qué algo no anda. Mi consejo es no usarlo casi nunca.

Answer (score 0):

prueba eso por favor:

si pones el IP público del VPS en server y client script te tendría que funcionar si arreglas este pequeño error:

srtlen -> strlen

```
$ php ./socketclient.php

Conexion Exitosa, puerto: 10000TE HAS CONECTADO PERFECTAMENTE
```

no puedes acceder a un servidor desde fuera sin usar su IP. Y el script del servidor también tiene que usar el IP público.